# Cannot be used as a JSX component. Its return type 'Promise<Element>' is not a valid JSX element

Tags: promise, react-typescript

I have an `React Component` `Editor`. I am trying to `initialize` the `state` using an `async` function. But I am unable to .

How we can do that in `React`.

```
const Editor = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const [schemas, updateSchemas] = useAtom(bfsAtom);
  const schema = id && _.get(schemas, id, {});

  type InitialStateType = {
    properties: KeyedProperty[];
    validations: ValidationDataProperty[];
  };
  const getInitialState = async (): Promise<InitialStateType> => {
    return {
      properties: createPropertiesFromSchema(schema),
      validations: initializeConditions(schema),
    };
  };

  const initialState = await getInitialState();

  const mainReducer = (
    { properties, validations }: InitialStateType,
    action: Action
  ) => ({
    properties: propertyReducer(properties, action),
    validations: validationReducer(validations, action),
  });
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(mainReducer, initialState);

  return (
    <PropertyContext.Provider value={{ state, dispatch }}>
      <SchemaEditor schema={schema}  />
    </PropertyContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** moving the `async` from top level to inside the component did the trick

---

Is not directly linked with your question but one thing that I was doing wrong is the following:

I had a component that looked like:

```
const MyComponent = async () => {
   ...
   const apiResponse = await apiFunction();

   return <div>
     
     {apiResponse.success && (
       <p>It was a success!</p>
     )}

   </div>
}
```

**BUT** you shouldn't use `async` in your components at top level. So **to fix it** I did this:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
   ...
   const apiResponse = async () => {
     return await apiFunction();
   }

   return <div>
     
     {apiResponse().success && (
       <p>It was a success!</p>
     )}

   </div>
}
```